# Let's start offering bounties!

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

Somehow I became the highest rep user on this site, and since I have no use for my rep points (14.5k at the moment) I'll start investing them in bounties for ignored or interesting questions, both new and old.

This might encourage some of the less active users to participate with quality answers, and might dilute the flood of [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions. It might attract new users who might see these bounties as low-hanging fruit for quick rep, hopefully retaining them for the future.

I highly encourage the higher rep users to invest their rep points. Maybe each one of us should have at least one bounty active at a time?

Comment: Thanks for your generosity. Can you offer a bounty on this one - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13327/electricity-in-clouds-and-induced-magnetism ?

Comment: @Muze in future do not offer any bounties. If you need to offer a bounty look at this question here.